# Graph of a logarithmic function

Tags: logarithms, exponential-function

When deriving the graph of a logarithmic function, why does the graph have to be reflected after interchanging the x and y axes? Is it possible for the axes of a graph to be changed? If so why?

Comment: I have no idea what you are asking!  First, what do you mean by "deriving" the graph of a logarithmic function?  And isn't "interchanging the x and y axes" the SAME as "reflecting the graph" in the line y= x?  Why should you do both?  Please given an example problem.

Comment: Are you talking about going from the graph of $y=e^x$ to the graph of $ln(x)$? Draw the $e^x$ graph on paper with a dark pen and put it up to a window. Turn it over and put the x axis vertical. That is now $x = ln(y)$.

Answer (score 1):

Because

$$y=\log x\iff x=e^y.$$

If you are able to plot the graph of the exponential, then you can draw that of the logarithm by swapping the axis.

This works with all direct and inverse function pairs, such as $$y=x^3\iff x=\sqrt[3]y$$ and so on.

Answer (score 0):

Attempt:

1)Consider $y=f(x)$; or $(x,f(x))$.

Example: $y=e^x$; or $(x,e^x);$

2) Reflection about the line $y=x$:

Point $(a,b) \rightarrow (b,a)$.

Example: $(x,e^x) \rightarrow (e^x,x)$.

3) We are looking for something like $(x,F(x))$.

4) How to get from $(e^x,x)$ to $(x,F(x))$?

5) Set $X:=e^x$ ($>0$).

The inverse function:

$Y=\log X =x$; or instead of

$(e^x,x)$ we can write

$(X,Y) =  (X,\log X)$ where $X >0$.